# OpenCV VideoCapture not working with GStreamer plugin

Tags: python, camera, raspicam, opencv, gstreamer

Running the following code on my raspberry pi 4b with the camera v2 and OpenCV installed via `pip install opencv-python` I have no issues:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.isOpened() # True
```

However, when I installed OpenCV with the manual build described [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), with the following variables:

```
export CMAKE_ARGS="-DENABLE_NEON=ON -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON -DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON"
export ENABLE_CONTRIB=1
```

Running the same code gives this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-4nusm4mm/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1825) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory.
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-4nusm4mm/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-4nusm4mm/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-4nusm4mm/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

I believe I have all the required dependencies and gstreamer libs. I have tried multiple different things including changing /dev/video0 permissions and `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` all to no avail.

OpenCV version 4.5.1,
GStreamer version 1.14.4

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when using raspberrypi camera the problem was that it outputs NV12 format not RGB
you can use this code to test your camera https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/CSI-Camera

or just add "format=(string)NV12" as a parameter of cv2.VideoCapture